# Condition formatting

Tags: excel

I have made a gantt chart in excel and trying to make a conditional format where if the start date equals the end date then the cell should be filled. This will represent a milestone since I did not know any other way to do it. I tried to look for some examples but could not find any.

[image]

Comment: Please give us a screenshot at least so we can see what you mean.

Comment: I added a pic @Enigmativity

Comment: _Which_ cell should be filled?

Comment: I am trying to fill in the given cell shown in the calendar with a scroll bar. I want to add some sort of milestone indication, so at that given date the cell should be colored.

Comment: @danielahmad - I see at least 5 dates on that image. I think you need to be clearer about what you're trying to acheive.